# jQuery DataTables and Initial Data Load

Tags: jquery, datatables

I asked this question on the jQuery Datatable forum but it wasnt much help.  If anyone has worked with jQuery datatables and got it to work by setting the initial data when requesting the options, and not having the ajax call go out for page 1.  When my sAjaxSource is set during the init stage it automatically makes the request out again to load the data even though I initialized it with data.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6459/load-initial-data-without-ajax-call#Item_3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I think you are looking for the iDeferLoading feature.](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "iDeferLoading": 57
    } );
} );
```

UPDATE: I just read your question in the forum. Perhaps your problem is not so simple after all, but I would need to see your datatables set up in order to give you a more informed opinion.

I use datatables in a production environment and I know a bit about the API; but again, without looking at your setup and understanding exactly what's the deal with your second ajax call, it's difficult to help. I'll leave this answer here for what it's worth.

Comment: I think that you actually got the point: he didn't want an ajax call when the pages load and that's exactly what he got with your solution i think

Comment: I actually found iDeferLoading before I came back to this post, but it actually worked.  But it is iDeferLoading: true, not 57.

Comment: @Mike Flynn I posted the piece of code from the datatables website. I don't use the iDeferLoading feature myself, but it's strange that is called that way because the `i` in iDeferLoading stands for `integer` so it should be an int. Perhaps you are referring to the `bDeferLoading` parameter (`b` stands for bool)? I believe both parameters are valid and each serves a different purpose. `iDeferLoading` is just to tell datatables how many records are initially loaded w/o making the ajax request so that the pagination control can show the proper count and paging (like page 1 - 10 out of 57 rows)

Comment: No you are right.  I figured that out but forgot to update this post.