# Why does this DataTables Ajax call not work properly?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to get dataTables plugin to work with information for a website. I have read the [documentation](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and [various](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7949/getting-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-in-chrome-error/p1) [support](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6101/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-with-ajax-source/p1) threads for datatables as well as [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629423/using-ajax-to-load-a-jquery-datatable) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566899/jquery-data-tables-server-side-processing-not-working-as-expected) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440184/jquery-datatables-and-initial-data-load), to no avail in resolution. According to the above documentation, the code I have should work just fine... it doesn't.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
 $('#results_table').dataTable( {
  'bServerSide': true,
  'sAjaxSource': 'results.php',
  'fnServerParams': function ( aoData ) {
    aoData.push( { 't': Math.random() }); 
    }
   });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='results'>
  <table id='results_table' >
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Num</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Access date</th>
    <th>Access name</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
</div>
```

PHP snippet (after retrieving/formatting SQL data:

```
$output = array('sEcho'=>1,'iTotalRecords'=>$count, 'iTotalDisplayRecords'=>$count, 'aaData'=> $results);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Returned data (small subset of the total for testing):

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3,"aaData":[["1707052901-1A","D","Aug 17, 2012 1:54 PM","aqr"],["1707052901-1A","C","Aug 17, 2012 1:53 PM","aqr"],["2835602-4A","D","Aug 15, 2012 7:39 AM","aqr"]]}
```

Now, when I load the page with datatables I receive an *extremely* helpful answer regarding -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:49

and the table does not populate with information.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong; why does my implementation of server-side processing for dataTables not work?? How can I fix this to display properly?

Comment: I've only used datatables once since 1.9 was released. fnServerParams doesn't look right to me. I've just looked back at my scripts and they all use: 'fnServerData'. Also without 'fnCallback' passed as an argument to the function the table will not draw from memoery. On a totally seperate note, are you passing 'sEcho = 1' back to the page everytime?

Comment: @DavidBarker Currently, I am passing `sEcho=1` every page load, due to there being no `$_GET['sEcho']` variable on the first load. The documentation says that this value must be returned/supplied. `The next most common reason for server-side processing not working is the sEcho variable not being returned as it was set in the request. DataTables uses sEcho to keep a draw count, so this is an important parameter`

Comment: It is indeed :) glad you got this sorted. The reason I mentioned sEcho is that it must be passed back as it is recieved, not always 1, or your redraws will never work :P

Comment: @DavidBarker : right, thanks for that information. Having another issue now with the damn datatables not even doing the initial draw on load. Is it too much to ask for a non frustrating damn example from these guys??

Comment: ha, Datatables was very very frustrating indeed when I started using it. The documentation, though resourceful isn't really very helpful for first time users.. especially when you are using the server side processing. If it helps I've got some time if you want to come into chat, can share my worknig scripts with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aoData.push( { 't': Math.random() });
```

should be used like this:

```
aoData.push( { 'name': 't', 'value':Math.random() });
```

not sure if this is the issue, but this fixed some of my problems when using datatables

Comment: Well thanks; that one tweak made my data show up! Now, I have a few other layout and data size issues to work on!

Comment: Just post a new question if you need any more help :)

Comment: Hi, I'm from the future. This did it for me too.